# htaccess protec ONLY Indexes files but not the rest

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to make a list with hotlink files, but the problem is that .htaccess is protecting only files like php html htm and it doesnt work with files like css js png, etc.
It doesnt work even using Order Denny,Allow. For example, in my htaccess i have this code

```
<Files demo.php>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 111.111.111.111 localhost
</Files>

<Files demo.js>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 111.111.111.111 localhost
</Files>
```

I change my IP and when i hit mydomain.com/demo.php is working, i mean i got 403 Forbidden. 
But if i hit mydomain.com/demo.js it doesnt work. I mean, i still see demo.js
Same thing is happeing when i try to protect a js file. Hotlinking it doesnt work either

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http://mydomain\.com/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*js$ - [F]
```

Is there an apache misconfiguration that i dont know? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a front-end server before apache, that serves static files (js, css, images, etc.)
You should limit access to these files in the front-end configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will check right now but first want to tell that i have installed Cloudflare when i got the VPS, so i installed  "cloudflare_module". So do you think it could be cloudflare causing this truoble?